# How can I get realtime updates from facebook graph api for friend checkins?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin

Is it possible to get real-time updates from Facebook's graph API for a user's friend's check-ins?

I know you can get friend check-ins on demand and can get user check-ins real-time, how about friend check-ins real-time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the real time updates from the facebook graph api by using the subscriptions

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>/subscriptions?object=check_in&callback_url=<ur url>
```

. Refer the below link for details

http://vikasrao.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/subscribing-to-facebook-graph-apis-real-time-updates-using-curl/

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding the curl scripts from the blogpost directly in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get RTUs for a user's friends' checkins.  Just the user's checkins, and even so you must enable 'feed' in the subscription, not 'checkins'.  Currently a documentation bug.